# Compilation error on PGFPlot example 10

Tags: pgfplots, packages, installing, acrotex

I've been trying to compile some [PGFPlots](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/) examples on OSX with TexLive on MacOS.

The first ([`example_0.tex`](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html)) compiles fine, but `example_10.tex` fails with the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `insdljs.sty' not found.
```

## What have I tried

### Environment variables

Following the relevant part in [the manual](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf), downloaded the package manually to `/Users/adamatan/Personal/latex-packages` and added these lines to my `.zshrc`:

```
export TEXDOCS=/Users/adamatan/Personal/latex-packages//:
export LUAINPUTS=/Users/adamatan/Personal/latex-packages//:
export TEXINPUTS=/Users/adamatan/Personal/latex-packages//:
```

### Finding the file

Tried finding `insdljs.sty` on my filesystem using `locate`, but found nothing.

### Search

Searched the web for the mysterious `insdljs.sty`, but could not find anything of significance.

## Details

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
% translate with >> pdflatex -shell-escape <file>

% This file is an extract of the PGFPLOTS manual, copyright by Christian Feuersaenger.
% 
% Feel free to use it as long as you cite the pgfplots manual properly.
%
% See
%   http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf
% for the complete manual.
%
% Any required input files (for <plot table> or <plot file> or the table package) can be downloaded
% at
% http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/latex/
% and
% http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/latex/plotdata/

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pagestyle{empty}

\usepgfplotslibrary{clickable}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
    clickable coords={(xy): \thisrow{label}},%
    scatter/classes={%
        a={mark=square*,blue},%
        b={mark=triangle*,red},%
        c={mark=o,draw=black}}]
    \addplot[scatter,only marks,%
        scatter src=explicit symbolic]%
    table[meta=label] {
x     y      label
0.1   0.15   a 
0.45  0.27   c 
0.02  0.17   a 
0.06  0.1    a 
0.9   0.5    b 
0.5   0.3    c 
0.85  0.52   b 
0.12  0.05   a 
0.73  0.45   b 
0.53  0.25   c 
0.76  0.5    b 
0.55  0.32   c
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Error Log

```
 $ /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex example_10.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./example_10.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31>
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.revision.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.te
x
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-li
sts.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.c
ode.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.d
ef
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-p
df.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.
code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.
tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigo
nometric.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.rando
m.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.compa
rison.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integ
erarithmetics.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconst
ruct.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicst
ate.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransform
ations.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.c
ode.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathproce
ssing.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.cod
e.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.
code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretranspare
ncy.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.
code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.
tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-0-65.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-1-18.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.cod
e.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothan
dlers.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotscore.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/sys/pgfplotssysgeneric
.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/pgfplotslibrary.c
ode.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplot
soldpgfsupp_loader.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryfpu.cod
e.tex)
Package pgfplots: loading complementary arithmetics for your pgf version...

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplot
soldpgfsupp_pgflibraryfpu.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplot
soldpgfsupp_pgfmathfloat.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsutil.code
.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplots
liststructure.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplots
liststructureext.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplots
array.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplots
matrix.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/numtable/pgfplotstable
shared.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplots
deque.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsbinary.co
de.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsbinary.da
ta.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsutil.verb
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/pgflibrarypgfplot
s.surfshading.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/sys/pgflibrarypgfplots
.surfshading.pgfsys-pdftex.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotscolormap.
code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotscolor.cod
e.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsstackedplots.c
ode.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsplothandlers.c
ode.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsmeshplothandle
r.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsmeshplotimage.
code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.scaling.code.
tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotscoordprocessin
g.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.errorbars.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.markers.code.
tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsticks.code.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.paths.code.te
x)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarydecorations.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduledecoration
s.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarydecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorations/pgfli
brarydecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarydecorations.pathreplacing.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorations/pgfli
brarydecorations.pathreplacing.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibraryplotmarks.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplotmar
ks.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgfplots/libs/tikzlibrarypgfplots
.clickable.code.tex

! LaTeX Error: File `insdljs.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name:
```

### Tex Version

```
 $ /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex --version
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016)
kpathsea version 6.2.2
Copyright 2016 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.21; using libpng 1.6.21
Compiled with zlib 1.2.8; using zlib 1.2.8
Compiled with xpdf version 3.04
```

Comment: It's part of the AcroTeX bundle, as mentioned in the `pgfplots` manual: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/insdljs?lang=en If you don't need the clickable stuff, remove the library, and the `clickable coords=...` in the `axis` options.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea how to install it on MacOs? I've searched `insdljs` and `acrotex` in the TeX Live Utility and found nothing.

Comment: No, they're not available in TeX Live (as mentioned implicitly on CTAN -- it only lists MikTeX availability). I'm sure there are some posts around here describing that better than I can, but short answer: download the `.ins` and `.dtx`, then run `pdflatex insdljs.ins` to generate the `.sty` file. For a one-off, place the `.sty` in the same folder as the `.tex` file.

Comment: Here's a link for the AcroTeX distribution: http://www.acrotex.net/index.php?lang=en&page=welcome